# checking multiple keys in a dictionary is not working. python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing an if statement to determine if my dictionary has multiple keys. If not i just want to pass. I thought if the code below did not find 'redshift' as a key it would pass. However when i run it redshift is not a key and it does not pass. I get a Key error. What is the problem. As long as it finds 'redshift' or 'host' it is not passing.

```
        print config[name].keys() 
        if ("redshift" and "host") in config[name]: 
            print config[name].keys() 
            name.append(config[name]["name"])
            redshift.append(config[name]["redshift"][0]['value'])
            type.append(config[name]["type"][0]["value"])
         else:
            pass
```

Comment: what is the value of `config` here? Please provide an example.

Comment: You are looping using `for la in config[name]:` but never used `la` inside the loop once?

Comment: config is called in form a .json file. one example is, config[SNname].keys=[u'discoverer', u'redshift', u'claimedtype', u'sources', u'maxabsmag', u'aliases', u'hostdec', u'comovingdist', u'maxappmag', u'maxdate', u'ra', u'hostra', u'lumdist', u'maxband', u'host', u'discoverdate', u'dec', u'name', u'spectra', u'ebv', u'velocity', u'photometry']

Comment: yes i have taken the la loop out it had no purpose

Comment: hint: type `"redshift" and "host"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `("redshift" and "host") in config[name]` does not test if both keys are present.

`("redshift" and "host")` produces *just* `"host"`, because `and` returns either the first expression if false according to its [truth value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), otherwise the second expression is returned. So in the end, all you are really testing is the expression `"host" in config[name]`.

Use two separate `in` tests:

```
if "redshift" in config[name] and "host" in config[name]:
```

or test for with a set against the dictionary with [`set.issubset()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset):

```
if {'redshift', 'host'}.issubset(config[name]):
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the most efficient ways to do such a check is to use intersections of sets:

```
In [62]: config
Out[62]: {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb', 'c': 'ccc'}

In [63]: len({'a','b'} & config.keys())
Out[63]: 2

In [64]: len({'a','Z'} & config.keys())
Out[64]: 1
```

so checking the length of the intersection will show whether all your values were found in keys

How it works:

```
In [65]: {'a','b'} & config.keys()
Out[65]: {'a', 'b'}

In [66]: {'a','XXX'} & config.keys()
Out[66]: {'a'}
```

Comment: Why produce a whole new set for the intersection? All you need to test for is if there is a subset.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks for the hint! I thought it might be faster this way. I have updated my answer

Comment: Your code, as posted, only works on Python 3, by the way. In Python 2 you'd have to use `{...} & config.viewkeys()`.

Comment: `[...]` creates a **list**, not a set, a type that doesn't support the `&` operator. Use `{...}`